# Call external program on link under cursor with Emacs

Tags: emacs, elfeed

I use `elfeed` to read RSS.
In each RSS there is an http link to a torrent file.
And I want to call an external program (`aria2c`) to download that torrent link, assuming that there is no such tool within Emacs.

How to write a small function to do this?

Comment: In `dired` mode, you can open a file with an external program by pressing `!` and type name of the program. I'm not sure if this helps, but you can take a look to see how `dired` implement this feature

Comment: A quick search on melpa leads to this rTorrent client: https://github.com/skangas/mentor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here a simple solution:

```el
(defun open-with-ariac2()
 (interactive)
 (shell-command
     (format (concat "aria2c " (browse-url-url-at-point)))))
```